# PLATFORM and PLATFORMNAME macros in VS2008 and VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, configuration, platform

I have got an old project, C++, 64 bits compiled on VS2008. The project is built using some Python scripts (SCONS). I have got to compile it in VS2010.
All is working pretty fine except one small detail: in VS2008 all output goes to Debug\Win64 or Release\Win64, where scripts are looking for it, while in VS2010 it goes to Debug\x64 or Release\x64.

I know that there are PLATFORM/PLATFORMNAME macros being used by VS.  Anything I did trying to change these values is mighty ignored by VS, or, if I am changing it manually in vcxproj files, VS refuses to compile at all.

For some company-related reasons scripts could not be changed. So for now I just added to a batch file that runs the script some xcopy commands to copy all the files from\x64 to \win64 before the script starts. It's kind of working, but I would like to know about a more elegant solution.

Thanks,
fLot

Comment: Just remove $(PlatformName) from the settings in the General settings page.  You'd better remove the Win32 configuration as well to make sure that it doesn't overwrite the 64-bit build output.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that might work is to create a file system junction so that \Win64 and \x64 becomes two different names to the same physical folder. You have to create a junction for each configuration instead of copying the files but once created it should stick between builds and ensure the two folders have the same content. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point.